# Fetch data which is not in another table

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have two table named test and result.

- If candidates register then it will be inserted in test table.
- If candidate completed test then details has been inserted into result table.

Now I need a query to compare two table and populate detail candidates those who are not complete the test by using candidate id. I am using zend frame work please guide me
  I am using this code but it does not work

```
$dbTableInfo = $this->getDbTable()->info(); 
$select->from(array(
    'c1' => 'test'),
    array('c1.candidate_id', 
        "CONCAT( c1.first_name,
        ' ', 
        c1.last_name ) AS full_name",
    'c1.active',
    'c1.sendlink', 
    'c1.date_added',
    'c1.username',
    'c1.date_modified', 
    'c1.test_id')
);
$select->joinLeft(array('re'=>'result'));
$select->where("c1.business_id='" . $cid . "' AND 'c1.candidate_id NOT IN(re.candidate_id)'");
$select->order('c1.candidate_id');
```

Comment: please put up the whole query. For example what is the $select variable? Is it a Zend_Db_Select() or Zend_Db_Statement() or just a plain string? Also what fetch are you trying to use and in what context? Is this a mapper, a DbTable or controller?

Comment: formatting the code properly immediately shows an unclosed quote (`"`)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not answering your question, but why don't you simply use a single table with a *discriminator* field, which would be called *type* for example, and use it this way:

- If a candidate registers he will be inserted with *type* set to *test*
- If a candidate completed the tests then his *type* would be changed to *completed*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to specify condition In joinLeft?

Answer (score 0):

from [zend docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html) :

> LEFT JOIN with the joinLeft(table, condition, [columns]) method. All
>   rows from the left operand table are included, matching rows from the
>   right operand table included, and the columns from the right operand
>   table are filled with NULL if no row exists matching the left table.

and in your query you didnt specify neither the condition nor the columns you want returned.

for example you can do your join like this :

```
$select->from(array(
    'c1' => 'test'),
    array('c1.candidate_id', 
        "CONCAT( c1.first_name,
        ' ', 
        c1.last_name ) AS full_name",
    'c1.active',
    'c1.sendlink', 
    'c1.date_added',
    'c1.username',
    'c1.date_modified', 
    'c1.test_id')
);
$select->joinLeft(
            array('re'=>'result'),
            '"c1".candidate_id = "re".candidate_id',
             "*"
);
```